# Angular2 post but still can not get the value in struts with actions

Tags: angular

This is my service.ts:

```
private urlConfigData = "/GATS-QTI-NG/generationconfigfile.action";

generateConfigfile(data): Observable<any>{

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });

return this.http.post(this.urlConfigData, "hello", options)

                .map((response: Response) => console.log(response))
                .catch (this.handleError);
}
```

component.ts:

```
const req = 
     this.integrationTestService.generateConfigfile(this.configDataGroup)
    .subscribe(
    res => {
        console.log(res);
      },
      err => {
        console.log("Error occurred");
      })
```

The result on the Java side is null.  I also changed the url to this but with no effect:

```
private urlConfigData = "/GATS-QTI-NG/generationconfigfile.action?data=";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it has worked for me,

My component method,

```
import {Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

var response = this.service.post('your...url/hello', null);
    response.subscribe((res) => {
    var response = res.json();
});
```

Service Post method,

```
post(url: string, data : any): Observable<any> {
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});
      return this.http.post(url, data,options);
```

}